# Is 'clamp' a formally recognized mathematical function?

Tags: functions, terminology

I was surprised to find the `clamp` function absent from [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?query=clamp&x=0&y=0) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamp). Is this mainly a concept particular to computer programming? Is it known by another name in mathematics? I'll be editing the Wikipedia shortly to include a reference to this function but I want to make sure I'm not omitting some synonymous terms I'm currently unaware of.

$$
  \operatorname{clamp}(x) = \max( a , \min( x , b ) ) \in [a,b]
$$

Comment: Mathematics doesn't make significant use of such a function (and when it does, it will inevitably be defined *in situ*).

Comment: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sugar-function-clamp/ is this what you refer? It's a math function specific to an R language library. There are references to it's usage in the link(points to some Stackoverflow questions). Mathworld wouldn't reference it since it's R specific.

Comment: you have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)

Comment: @janmarqz Didn't even bother to take a look at the graphics entry having read its brief synopsis.  They're indeed using clamping for the implementation of that operation. Good catch.

Comment: @Chappers good terminology there, in situ definition, I didn't realize that concept was formalized. I like it.

Answer (score 6):

There's no such thing as a "formally recognized" mathematical function. Some are more well known and widely used, but there is no standard defining what is a recognized function. Yes, $\mathop{\rm clamp}(x)$ is a mathematical function.

Comment: I was just beginning to question that terminology I used, what's the appropriate term for things we assign names to such as sinc, sine, cosine, unit step, tangent, etc. Elementary functions?

Comment: From Wikipedia "In mathematics, an elementary function is a function of one variable built from a finite number of exponentials, logarithms, constants, and nth roots through composition and combinations using the four elementary operations (+ – × ÷)."

Comment: Looks like $clamp(x)$ is a projection onto an interval, which is used a lot in optimization (tho I have never heard it called "clamp").  Regardless, it is best to define it when you introduce it. I have used this function a lot but I called it  $[x]_{a}^{b}$.  If you minimize a convex function $f(x)$ of one variable $x$ over all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and the minimum is $x^* \in \mathbb{R}$, then the min value of $f(x)$ over the restricted interval $[a,b]$ is $[x^*]_a^b=clamp_{ab}(x^*)$.  Here I am taking the liberty to put subscripts on your function to specify the interval.

Comment: For example, given constants $C> 0$ and $D$, the minimum of $Cx^2+Dx$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is at $x^* = -D/(2C)$, and the min over $x \in [a,b]$ is $[-D/(2C)]_a^b$.

Answer (score 3):

I remember using it in measure theory to show that a function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ was almost everywhere differentiable. The idea was that the clamp function was used to extend the identity $[a,b] \to [a,b]$ to the whole of $\mathbb R$, and then we could compose the clamp with $f$ to extend $f$ to the reals. This was just the first step of the proof, the clamp function had nothing to do with the rest. But I don't remember giving a name to that function ; I guess it just doesn't have enough importance in theoretical applications. It sounds more like a programmer's function.

Hope that helps,