# Special name for a function

Tags: soft-question

Suppose we define the function $L(x)$ as follows:
$$\begin{equation}
    L(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x<0 \\
      x, & \text{if}\ 0<x<1 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$

For example, suppose we have $x_i(t+1)=x_i(t)+1$, then we can write $x_i(t+1)=L[y_i(t)]$, where $y_i(t)=x_i(t)+1$.

Does the function $L(x)$ have a special name? Is it similar to an operator?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is an important special case of the function asked about in [MSE question 1336636](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336636) "Is 'clamp' a formally recognized mathematical function?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L$ is the CDF of the uniform distribution.

When you limit yourself to $(0,1)$, it is the identity function.

Answer (score 0):

I call $L(x)$ a **ramp** function, based on the picture it produces. It's not really that special of a name.

Comment: But the $x$ in $L(x)$ could also be a function. Actually in the case I am studying the term $x$ always represents a function of $x$ (i.e. $L[y(x)]$). I think by definition a ramp function simply maps real numbers to non-negative real numbers, right?