# Is there a name for function $f(x)=\max(a, \min(x, b))$, where $a \leq b$?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for function $f(x)=\max(a, \min(x, b))$, where $a \leq b$?
What actually this function does: it keeps value in bounds of $[a, b]$.

Comment: I only used this when checking if the number was between `-MAX_INT` and `MAX_INT`. 
 Probably, this does not have a name unless you name it yourself .. :).

Comment: I named and programmed it as `opt(x,a,b)=...`, and mostly use it to avoid IOOBE while accessing arrays, but for years I have doubts about name, and now have enough courage to ask question here :D

Comment: Is is called “clamp” in C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp, and also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)

Comment: Yes, this, thank you. I was sure that I already know about that, but for some reason nothing than "clip/clipping" sounds in my brain each time I tried to recall it. Please, post this as an answer, so I can nicely accept it. Or what should I do in this case if I don't need answers anymore?

Comment: On the interval [a,b] it's just f(x)=x. So on the interval [a,b] it's a straight line.

Comment: Yes, but $\exists x, x \notin [a, b]$. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3990121/34929) describes how line looks for all cases.

Comment: In some contexts "clipping" might be the correct term for what the function does. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336636/is-clamp-a-formally-recognized-mathematical-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is called “clamp” in the C++ standard library, and also in the OpenGL graphics library.

References:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp
- https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/clamp.xhtml
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Looks like I choose wrong StackExchange site to ask question, heh? But this is how I saw this question (in terms of min/max) despite it originally comes from programming area. But also answer is from that area.... hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any official "name" for this function. It is just a fancy way to express a [piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function). It is very likely that people write it in such a compact way for a purpose of [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604323/confusion-with-combining-math-max-and-math-min).

When $a=1$ and $b=4$, the graph of the function:

[image]