# Simplified notation for max(lb, min(x, ub))?

Tags: notation, maxima-minima

Let's say I want to saturate an argument number `x` to a lower-bound value `lb` if it is lower than `lb` and otherwise return `x` itself. Then I can use `max(lb, x)`. Analogously, I can use `min(x, ub)` if I have an upper bound `ub`.

Is there a function `f`, such that if I write `f(lb, x, ub)`, one understands that the return value is the respective one?

- `lb`, if `x < lb`;
- `ub`, if `x > ub`; and
- `x`, otherwise.

Or other notation simpler than writing `max(lb, min(x, ub))`.

Comment: Some of the references to this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336636/is-clamp-a-formally-recognized-mathematical-function , may give useful notation.  It's unlikely to be a well-known notation, so you should define it in any work where you use it.

Comment: Thank you @EricTowers. I really appreciated the references. Do you think my question should be flagged as a duplicate of the one you referred to?

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate.  There may be an exact duplicate ... somewhere.

Comment: Found the duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990111. So, I just flagged this question as a duplicate. I didn't find the duplicate before writing the question. But I found it now because it was linked to the one you referred to.